# Change logout redirect link to external page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, redirect, logout

After logging out from the account the user is redirected to a page that redirects to the CMS home page of magento.
I don't have that page and want to redirect to an external page instead.
But I can't find a clean way to change that redirect url to a page outside of magento.
I want to redirect to my page root whereas magento resides in `https://www.mymagento.com/shop/`.
The redirect should lead to `https://www.mymagento.com/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the logout phtml template and update the redirect url.

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml:14
```

Change the `$block->getUrl()` to the url where you want to be redirected.

```
$($.mage.redirect("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl() ?>", "assign", 5000));
```

Comment: @DarsVaeda is the solution working for you?

Comment: Yep, not the cleanest solution though but at least it works. Thanks.

Comment: How can we add an external URL?